# Labelling the GeoTIFF canvas symbology in QGIS3

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I used the Interpolation (Nearest neighbor) feature.
After watching this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By-K5C7jDQc&ab_channel=HansvanderKwast

I could set the color rendering for my values.

I also put labels next to them, because I want them visible next to the color band, as we used to see by contour lines and so on.

Unfortunately, they don't come out, as you can see below:

[image]

I though that the thread below will be helpful:

[How to add text on top of symbols for vector layers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326799/how-to-add-text-on-top-of-symbols-for-vector-layers-in-qgis)

But I can't see the label option in the Properties panel at all.

I want something like you to see below:

[image]

Is it possible with GeoTIFF band rendering?

Comment: That is for a vector layer. You seem to have a raster layer. It is also for the layout legend,  not the canvas legend.

Comment: Yes, I have the raster layer. So is it possible with the raster layer then?

Comment: I think you need to create a vector layer with point features where you want the labels. Then you can show the labels on the canvas.